# making a dent in the bottom edge of list view's cell

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview

I have been working on a list which is supposed to show some information from users. The list should show user's avatar and some other data. Below I have attached the specified design, avatar is shown in a circular image, which is slightly above the upper edge of cell, and the upper edge of avatar finishes at the bottom part of previous cell. All these is fine and I can do it, but as you can see in the picture, I need to make a dent in the bottom edge of previous cell, which matches the size of avatar's circular image.

Does anyone have any idea how this might be done? or any clue? I am really out of ideas now!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the actual list item has that dent?  If I were designing this app, my list item layout would end just above the dent; then the dent with the avatar, etc. be part of the next list item. The last list item would contain a straight closing bottom without the dent. The list would need to have item separator set to null, of course.

Comment: Well this design is from the designer and I haven't seen it in some other app. Your idea by far is my best bet for implementing this, Making the dent as part of the next cell and then setting divider length to 0px. But still I am not sure how to make the dent! The size of the curve should be proportional to upper part of the image,  while image's size can be different on different screen resolutions.  Any suggestions on this?